# Convert the return type into an object in python

Tags: python

I am reading some data from yaml and it returns it as dict type. But as per my requirement I have to read the return value as object only. So for example to access the read data I have to use object.tags not like object['tags'].

```
{'one': {'actual_data': [{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['value1']}], 'expected_data': {'id': '701', 'groups': [{'GroupName': 'group_new', 'GroupId': '4ae6'}], 'state': [{'Code': 560012, 'Name': 'Bangaladesh'}], 'address': 'Bangaladesh', 'tag': [{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'value1'}]}}, 'two': {'actual_data': [{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['value2']}], 'expected_data': {'id': '302', 'groups': [{'GroupName': 'group_new', 'GroupId': '4ae6'}], 'state': [{'Code': 560013, 'Name': 'Japan'}], 'address': 'Japan', 'tag': [{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'value2'}]}}}
```

To fetch the above resource my script

```
class Common:
    def __init__(self,parsed_data:dict):
        self.expected_data = parsed_data.get('expected_data')
        self.actual_data = parsed_data.get('actual_data')
        print(self.actual_data,self.expected_data)
    
    @classmethod
    def test_data(cls) -> list:
        test_data_file = "my yaml file location"
        with open (test_data_file) as data_file:
            data = yaml.load(data_file, Loader=SafeLoader)

        return data

    @classmethod
    def fetch_data_from_yaml(cls,resources:str) -> dict:
        read_data = cls.test_data()
        read_dict = {}
        if resources == 'add':
            read_dict = read_data['tags']['mul']
            
        return Common(read_dict)
```

This file called newone.py. I have one more file called newtwo.py. This newone.py and newtwo.py are inside the same directory.
I am calling the newone file method from newtwo file like below

```
from newone import Common


def new_func() -> list:
    fetched_object = Common.fetch_data_from_yaml('add')
    print(fetched_object.id)
```

When I run this new_func I am getting fetched object that doesn't have an id. I have to implement this because I have to use the page object model. The main idea is I have to read the YAML data as an object. can you please tell me how do I read this as the object?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the common object? Is it supposed to be a data transfer object (a class for holding data?)

Comment: But your class `Common` _doesn't_ have an attribute `id`. Why do you expect it to?

Comment: Also is there an actual good reason for you not to store the data as a dict? Or is this an arbitrary requirement someone is imposing on you.

Comment: Common object is to read the data from yaml. I have other resources for example if resources='div':read_dict = read_data['tags']['div'].

Comment: I have to fetch all these details which I have mentioned at the start of the question for example actual_data, id, state, groups.Id is actually located in the parsed_data, in the expected_data. I am not sure this is the correct way to access the id.

Comment: Ok, but why do you want your data stored as object attributes and not in a dict?

Comment: This is the requirements asked in my task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are already reading YAML as `Common` object.

If you want `id` or `tags` as an attribute of `fetched_object`, which is of `Common` type, you should define them in `Commam` `__init__` section and assign values to them.

```py
class Common:
    def __init__(self,parsed_data:dict):
        self.expected_data = parsed_data.get('expected_data')
        self.tags = parsed_data['expected_data']['tag']
        self.id = parsed_data['expected_data']['id']
        self.actual_data = parsed_data.get('actual_data')
        print(self.actual_data,self.expected_data)
```

Comment: This, doesn't appear to be related to the question

Comment: @nick-bailey it was a misunderstanding, I corrected the answer.

Comment: When I try this it's returning none

Comment: Do you mean `print(fetched_object.id)` prints `None`? If so, check if `parsed_data['expected_data']['id']` is the right path to `id` and if the YAML data file is correct.

Comment: Yes It worked now. There is some issue in my YAML